# What are some tips to connect to linux server remotely from windows and increase productivity?

Tags: remote-access

I have a windows computer and connect to Linux on a remote server for my experiments. I want to use an easy interface software from windows to my Linux server (ubuntu 18.04). Can you give some tips on how to increase productivity in such a workflow?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Putty is fast, but AFAIK, does not support tabs, you will have to open different windows for different tasks, unless you use a terminal multiplexer like screen.

Try Mobaxterm and see if you like it. It is free, and supports multiple tabs, very handy for a single session.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It wasn't mine, but I imagine it was because the question is so far off-topic that it should either be flagged for closure or ignored.